# Xpath: select node value with local-name()

Tags: xml, xpath, biztalk

I want get the value between the open/close tags.

In this example all the field are inside the tag "PARAM " where the name is different.

Following, one of the xml examples.
in this particular case, my objective is read the "21" in name="project_id".

XML sctructure:

```xml
<test>
    <MESSAGE type="Update" />
    <PARAMETERS>
        <PARAM name="project_id">21</PARAM>
        <PARAM name="project_name">000000003|teste name project</PARAM>
        <PARAM name="enabled">true</PARAM>
        <PARAM name="start_time">2019,02,01,00,00,00</PARAM>
        <PARAM name="end_time">2020,09,30,00,00,00</PARAM>
        <PARAM name="created_in">admin</PARAM>
    </PARAMETERS>
</test>
```

At this moment i have this xPath:

```xml
/*[local-name()='ULM' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='PARAMETERS' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='PARAM' and namespace-uri()=''][1]/@*[local-name()='name'and namespace-uri()='']
```

This xPath, only returns "project_id" but i need the value.

I already try using several xPaths, but only return the "project_id"(text).

Can someone give me a tip or indicate some article?

Thanks

xPath-Tester : https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Can someone give a tip?

Comment: If the namespace-uri is '', why do you need to use local-name()? Can't you just use `//PARAM[@name='project_id']/text()`?

Comment: I need user local-name(), because de program (biztalk) is given error when put an xPath without local-name(). 
The xPath ( /ULM/PARAMETERS/PARAM[@name='project_id'])  work very well in the freeformatter.com, but when deploy this do biztalk, the server retrieve an error saying: "cannot recognize the xpath".

Comment: Solution founded. /*[local-name()='ULM']/*[local-name()='PARAMETERS']/*[local-name()='PARAM' ][1]/text()

Comment: Someone with other Solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

From your sample, the following XPath expression work :

```
//*[name()="PARAM" and @*[name()="name"]="project_id"]/text()
```

Output : 21

Replace `name()` with `local-name()` if errors occur.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add condition on `<PARAM>` element based on your `@name` attribute equals to `'project_id'`, then you can get the resulting `text()` value based on this condition.

```
/*[local-name()='ULM'  and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='PARAMETERS' and amespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='PARAM'][@*[local-name()='name' and namespace-uri()='']='project_id'][1]/text()
```

Since you are not using any namespaces based on your given xml, you can ignore  and `namespace-uri()=''`.

```
/*[local-name()='ULM']/*[local-name()='PARAMETERS']/*[local-name()='PARAM'][@*[local-name()='name']='project_id'][1]/text()
```